# install mysql proxy via ubuntu terminal

Tags: 12.04, mysql, proxy

How do i install MySql Proxy via ubuntu terminal

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-proxy-install-binary.html

Comment: did you download the `.tar.gz` file?

Comment: yeah @AvinashRaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go into the directory which contains `mysql-proxy-0.8.2-platform.tar.gz` from terminal.
- After that run the below command to extract the mysql-proxy-0.8.2-platform.tar.gz file inside the `/usr/local`.

  ```
  tar zxf mysql-proxy-0.8.2-platform.tar.gz -C /usr/local
  ```
- To set the environment path

  ```
  su root
  PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql-proxy-0.8.2-platform/sbin
  ```

Comment: At which file should we set the environment variables?

Comment: @JerwinRoy http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-proxy-install-binary.html

Comment: ya its similar to that mentioned above right?

Comment: yep, @JerwinRoy